# Are these two queries same/give same output?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, correlated-subquery

Indepenedent subquery

```
SELECT Cust_Name
 FROM Customer_Details              
   WHERE Cust_ID
     IN
      (SELECT Cust_ID
        FROM Customer_Loan)                
          AND Cust_ID IN
        (SELECT Cust_ID
          FROM Customer_Fixed_Deposit);
```

Correlated subquery

```
SELECT Cust_ID
 FROM Customer_Details              
   WHERE Cust_ID
     IN
      (SELECT Cust_ID
        FROM Customer_Loan
         WHERE Customer_Loan.Cust_ID  = Customer_Details.Cust_ID)                
          AND Cust_ID IN
        (SELECT Cust_ID
          FROM Customer_Fixed_Deposit
   WHERE Customer_Fixed_Deposit.Cust_ID  = Customer_Details.Cust_ID);
```

We ought to find customers who opted for loan as well as FD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final output would be same for both.